# Displaying Ranked Country Information

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I want to display the production quantities for lentil by country, i.e. countries that produced more would be highlighted in a darker color. A similar example can be found [here](https://www.fao.org/faostat/en/#data/QCL).

Answer (score 4):

Graduated colors symbology is used to show quantitative differences between features mapped. Just go through the [Using graduated colors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-graduated-colors.htm) page from the Help which describes the procedure.